# Change permission folder in Raspberry Pi to R permission

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, raspbian

The image below contain the command that change the permission for folder:

[image]

I want to change permission folder in Raspberry Pi to `r` permission it is folder for radio in `/var/www`. It failed and said *`"chmod: invalid mode: '-R' try chmod :--help to more information"`*.

Comment: The `-R` flag does not specify a permission level, it means "recursive". Type `man chmod` for more information, or visit [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

Comment: Please do not post links to photos describing your question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned `-R` is not a permission, rather it's an option that sets the recursive mode on. The command you want is:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R PiFmRds/src
```

Note: chmod 777 is a dangerous permission setting. It means that literally everyone and everything can read, write, and execute the directory and everything below it.